# Search for rows in Excel via Microsoft Graph API

Tags: excel, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I've built a scanner app that scans a barcode which acts as an ID. Now I need to find this item in a SharePoint Excel file using the Microsoft Graph API and perform actions with it.

*Note:
The file, sheet, and table are all known beforehand.*

For example, I want to retrieve row 5, with the only know parameter being Roll ID: ***B5***

[image: I need to find the 5th row by the value of the 2nd column "Roll ID"]

I've tried using filter methods, but they're not ideal for what I'm trying to build. I must be pushing this way over the limit as it's not a SQL database, but is there any way to get what I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand the limit of microsoft-graph, the only way to perform where query is using the Filter. So far, the filter works for me.

1. start the session with persist = false, `POST /createSession`
2. clear filter, `POST /tables/{table}/clearFilters`
3. apply filter, `-d "{ criteria: { filterOn: 'Custom', criterion: '=id' } }" POST /tables/{table}/column('{column}')/filter/apply`
4. fetch visible row, `GET /tables/{table}/range/visibleView/rows`
5. close the session.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So whenever I'm doing a query, I'm actually clearing the filter, applying a new filter, getting the visible rows and so on? It's not ideal to do 3 API requests for what's essentially one action, but it's better than nothing. Thanks!